# How to Add days to a date column along with time in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to add 1 day to  read_date column along with time.

below is the sample column data

```
read_date
-----------------------
01-01-19 01:00:00.000000000 AM


Expected Result
---------------------
02-01-19 01:00:00.000000000 AM
```

I have tried below but it is adding only day not time.

```
select read_time, read_time+1
from meter_read_alert

read_date                           read_date+1
------------------------------------------------------
01-01-19 12:00:00.000000000 AM      02-01-19
01-01-19 01:00:00.000000000 AM      02-01-19
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `+ 1`, the `timestamp` is converted to a `date`.  That is why you are only seeing the date (the default representation of a `date` does not include the time component although it is there).

Instead, use `interval`:

```
select read_time, read_time + interval '1' day
from meter_read_alert;
```

PS.  I learned something from this.  Interesting question.

Comment: "*That is why you are only seeing the date*" - no, the reason why she isn't seeing the time part is the obnoxious default behaviour of the Oracle tools to not display the time part of a `DATE` value. https://i.imgur.com/krLIdrE.png

Comment: Now i am confused who to give my upvote, To the answer or to comment? Finally to both.

Comment: `current_timestamp + 1` doesn't give '15.08.2019' only, but also contains hour,minute and second parts.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan . . . I clarified that point.  I didn't mean to imply that the time component was missing, only that the type is returned as a `date`.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . But *Oracle* is changing the type in that case.  That is the point of the  answer.  I didn't mean to imply that the time component is missing.